# htmlspecialchars not working as expected

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am probably using it wrong, the problem is this:
I have php code that gets echoed to the page like so:
`<?php echo "<h1>" . htmlspecialchars($array['text']) . "</h1>" ?>`

That variable gets echoed from the databse in an html structure like this

`echo "<h1> Hello </h1>"` This works fine, but as soon as I echo something like `"> text here"` everything breaks. The text appears at the beginning of the body and I can actually inject JS into it and .. it works.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, am I using `htmlspecialchars` wrong or is the problem from somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1');
```

This makes `htmlspecialchars` use `ISO-8859-1` encoding, which I assume is what you're using.

Regarding the third argument, called `encoding`, according to the [htmlspecialchars docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> If omitted, the default value of the encoding varies depending on the PHP version in use. In PHP 5.6 and later, the default_charset configuration option is used as the default value. PHP 5.4 and 5.5 will use UTF-8 as the default. Earlier versions of PHP use ISO-8859-1.

Comment: If anyone can provide more details I will add them to my answer. I'm not super familiar with encoding problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. And it looks like it was getting inserted at the beginning of the <body> because I was using user generated content inside the meta title and description tags, and this fixes that too :)